# Why does Firebase not get the data?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase just silently don't get the data.
I work on it a lot of time but still don't really understand what is a problem.
Probably it's very simple mistake so get my excuses please

```
fRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ids = dataSnapshot.child("dictionary").child("fruitIds").getValue(DictionaryIDs.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

DictionaryIds.class code

```
package com.example.asuper.mluvitslova;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DictionaryIDs {

    private ArrayList<String> fruitIds = new ArrayList<>();

    public DictionaryIDs() {

    }

    public DictionaryIDs(ArrayList<String> fruitIds) {
        this.fruitIds = fruitIds;
    }


    public void addFruitId(String id){
        fruitIds.add(id);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFruitIds(){
        return fruitIds;
    }

    public void setFruitIds(ArrayList<String> fruitIds){
        this.fruitIds = fruitIds;
    }

}
```

And in log just NOTHING

This code must just get me the DictionaryIds.class file but in fact Firebase just get me null object.

[Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tav8C.png)

Comment: Have you actually set anything to that child?

Comment: The child of `fruitIds` is another `fruitIds`. What happens if you do `dataSnapshot.child("dictionary").child("fruitIds").child("fruitIds").getValue(DictionaryIDs.class);`?

Comment: @TheWanderer Nothing. It still does not work. And gets 

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.asuper.mluvitslova.DictionaryIDs`

Answer (score 0):

Under the last `fruitIds` child, there are no `DictionaryIDs` objects, there are simple strings. To get all those ids, you need to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference fruitRef = rootRef.child("dictionary").child("fruitIds").child("fruitIds");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String id = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
fruitRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be all those ids.